# Strange HTML comment behavior

Tags: html, undefined-behavior

In my code, I have a form with radio buttons. The first radio button is displayed but the second (Repeat Every Week) is not? If I remove the comment markers then it all works fine. But why is it happening?

```
<!------------>
<%= radio_button_tag 'repeat_daily', 'freq' %>Repeat Every Day<br/>
<!------------>
...some code...
<!----------->
<%= radio_button_tag 'repeat_weekly', 'freq' %>Repeat Every Week<br/>
<!----------->
```

Comment: Sure these are all you HTML comments?

Comment: Yes, I even removed all other code and comments and just left this code

Comment: What if you put a space on the middle of your comments? Like: `<!-- --------- -->`. Maybe its parsing wrong commenting until the last. Idk.

Comment: So lesson learnt is that don't use `--` inside the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of expected, see [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4)

> A common error is to include a string of hyphens ("---") within a comment. Authors should avoid putting two or more adjacent hyphens inside comments.

Comment: thanks for that link. I suppose then I should use `=` or something else instead of `-`.